# Why is viewDidLayoutSubviews() being called when I move UISliders?

Tags: ios, constraints, viewcontroller

My ViewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method is being called repeatedly when I move a `UISlider`. (I needed it to be called once so I could figure out the size of a subview -- `viewDidLoad()` being too early in the process -- but it's being called ad infinitum as I drag the `UISlider`.)

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: There's no such method as `viewDidLoadSubviews`. What do you really mean?

Comment: Do you mean viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: "My ViewController's viewDidLayoutSubviews() method is being called repeatedly" So what? When view controller lifetime methods are called is not up to you. Your job is to implement and respond to them as needed. What's the question, even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UISlider` draws itself using subviews for the thumb and the parts of the track. Here's the view hierarchy of a trivial test app:

```
<UIWindow: 0x7d26cf90; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7d2609a0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7d25f0c0>>
   | <UIView: 0x7d27d530; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d27cec0>>
   |    | <UISlider: 0x7d27d700; frame = (14 225; 292 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d27d960>; value: 0.513699>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x7b755a50; frame = (150 15; 140 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b7559d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7b7551d0; frame = (-148 0; 288 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b755410>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7b755640; frame = (2 15; 148 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b755720>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d5c3450; frame = (134 0; 31 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d5c4750>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d5c44a0; frame = (-13 -6.5; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d5c6c20>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7d27daa0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d27ccf0>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7d27e020; frame = (0 480; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d27e0f0>>
```

Notice that the `UISlider` has a total of five descendant views. This is an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on, but it's helpful to understand what's going on.

When the slider needs to change its value, it stores its new value in an instance variable and sets its own `needsLayout` flag. Eventually, the run loop reaches the layout phase, and the view hierarchy layout is updated, starting at the window and working its way down the hierarchy. When it reaches the slider, the slider updates its subviews' frames according to its value and other instance variables.

If you need to know the size of a subview, you may want to call `layoutIfNeeded` yourself, then immediately get the size of the subview, so that the layout is happening under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `viewDidLoad` being too early, could you do your calculations in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` ?

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times for multiple reasons. You can't rely on or change the frequency of this being called (for example, it is called when the status bar changes height).